# "Gave up" - QuickCheck

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

I want use quickcheck in a function that tests if a Maclaurin series is equal to `1/x`, for `x>1` and `x<2`. However, for small values of n, quickcheck returns false tests. Additionally, if I put `n>100` restriction, for example, quickcheck returns:

> "Gave up! Passed only 0 tests.".

Here's my code:

```
prop_inv :: Float -> Int -> Property
prop_inv x n = (x>1 && x<2) && n>100 ==> inv x n == 1/x
```

(`inv x n` is the function that calculates the Maclaurin series.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way is to make a small newtype that only generates values in the desired range. For example:

```
newtype BetweenOneAndTwo = BOAT Float deriving Show
instance Arbitrary BetweenOneAndTwo where
    arbitrary = BOAT <$> Test.QuickCheck.choose (1, 2)

prop_inv (BOAT x) (NonNegative n) = inv x (n+100) == 1/x
```

Comment: I have this error "Ambiguous occurrence 'choose'" because we have a 'choose' definition on probability.hs and we need it.

Comment: And it request "No instance for (Show BetweenOneAndTwo)"

Comment: @FilipeNunes You can use qualified imports to differentiate between the two `choose`s, and you can add `deriving Show` at the end of the newtype declaration to get an auto-generated `Show` instance. I've updated the answer showing how to do these two things.

Comment: Still have this: 

*Main> quickCheck prop_inv
*** Failed! Falsifiable (after 2 tests and 1 shrink):
BOAT 1.8863573
NonNegative {getNonNegative = 0}

Comment: It's possible to evaluate only some decimal place in float in expression  inv x (n+100) == 1/x ?

Comment: @FilipeNunes, this is a whole different question.  Yes, but it's not built-in -- you have to program it using math tricks.